# Customize default Prompt options (camera to share) when I trigger camera in Firefox with code development

Tags: web-application, javascript, firefox

I am having 2 cameras in my PC. When I try to trigger camera in firefox it always opens a permission prompt box with a webcam options. But I don't want to show the camera options in the prompt box. So Is there any customizable thingy to customize the Prompt box for firefox by updated any javascript changes (I am a developer. So want to fix it by code updation itself for my web application)
Anyone please help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: Also it's not possible the prompt box is a security feature of firefox.None here is going to help you circumvent that

Comment: ok but can we change the camera options ? (It will list all the camera's from my device actually which collapse my camera selection feature in my web app ). I can see google meet, hangouts they do control on camera list and showing only one camera list there.. Any idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893787/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-video-cameras-attached-in-my-computer-using-javascript

Comment: thanks for the link. But I'm fine with getting the camera devices connected in my machine using javascript. What I want is a camera list control in **Permission prompt** like (meet, hangouts say even In my machine I have 2 camera devices we can see only one camera in meet permission prompt).

Comment: Please refer the link for see the differences https://ibb.co/wwc8ZGj

Comment: thats probably an error you made in the javascript code.

Comment: If my device having 2 cameras then firefox will show all of the list in Prompt right ? this is the default behavoiur. But I want override it like meet/hangout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104778/discussion-between-user10269224-and-vipul-nair).